# JAXB marshalling - String XML pretty-print not working on all objects of generic type org.w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a JAXB pojo that sometimes contain a generic `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

Such element is contained inside the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "businessObject")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public final class BusinessObjectWrapper {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = PureXmlElementAdapter.class)
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Object xmlElementHolder;

}
```

... which is itself contained into some other classes that all end up into my main pojo `MxML`.

When the `marshal` method of the `PureXmlElementAdapter.class` is called to marshal the content, the following code is executed:

```
Element v = this.element;
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
NodeList childNodes = v.getChildNodes();
for (int j = 1; j < (childNodes.getLength() - 1); j++) {
    Node node = document.importNode(childNodes.item(j), true);
    document.appendChild(node);
}
return document.getDocumentElement();
```

Now, what happens is that if I try to print into a string the `document` that I create using the following function:

```
public static String fromXmlDocument(Document document, Charset encoding) throws TransformerException {
    try(StringBuilderWriter sw = new StringBuilderWriter()) {
        Transformer transformer = TRANSFORMER_FACTORY.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding.name());
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(sw));
        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

... I end up with an XML document which is properly formatted.

However, when I try to build an XML string out of my `MxML` object using this code:

```
JAXBContext JAXB_CONTEXT = JAXBContext.newInstance(MxML.class, BusinessObjectWrapper.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = JAXB_CONTEXT.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, stringWriter); //this is the instance of MxML
return stringWriter.toString();
```

... then what happens is that the output XML string is properly formatted, except for the `org.w3c.dom.Element` that I returned in my `marshal` call just above that looks like containing one new extra line for each line:

```
<MxML>
   <something>
      <somethingOk>
         <item nb="1">2.3</item>
         <item nb="2">2.4</item>
      </somethingOk>
      <somethingElse>
         <businessObject>
            <someElement>

               <someOtherElement>

                  <item nb="1">2.3</item>

                  <item nb="2">2.4</item>

    </someOtherElement>

</someElement>
         </businessObject>
      </somethingElse>
   </something>
</MxML>
```

So to sum-up, the marshaling of the whole `MxML` class done by JAXB is:

- Clean on all the objects that are proper JAXB pojo classes
- On all the opening tags of the nested `org.w3c.dom.Element`, I end up with proper indentation but unexpected new lines
- On all the closing tags of the nested `org.w3c.dom.Element`, not only I have unexpected new lines but I also lose indentation (as it seems the indentation is respected across closing elements but overall it restarts from the root level of the document)

I really don't know how to print this XML properly as I don't see any difference between what I do using the `Transformer` and what JAXB may be doing behind the scenes.

Does anyone know how could I get the proper output please?